# text email template is not coming in the Mail

Tags: apex

```
As per the requirement I am sending a pdf file attachment to some email ids,I thought to include some static text to show in the email and i created one text template and added in the code ,but the text is not showing in the email.
```

here is the code
I used setTemplateId to show the template...

```
 Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attach = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            attach.setContentType('application/pdf');          
            attach.setFileName(************************);
            attach.setInline(false);
            attach.Body = body;

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new 
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where  
            name=:'CSPdfEmailtemplate'];
            mail.setUseSignature(false);
            mail.setToAddresses(Emailids);
            mail.setTemplateId(et.id);//here i am giving the id of template
            mail.setBccSender(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_classes_outbound_single) a singleEmailMessage using a template needs to have the id of a contact, user or lead with setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId) so you will need to add that.